# Reshaping dataset wide

Tags: stata

I have a dataset from a small clinic which looks something like this:

[image: Example tables]

What I am trying to do is make the top long form of the dataset look like the bottom wide form.

My code is the following:

```
reform date injury_code_1 .... , i(ID) j(VisitNum)
```

The error code I get is this:

> There are variables other than `a`, `b`, `ID`, `VisitNum` in your data.  They must be constant within `ID` because that is the only way they can fit into wide data without loss of information.
>
> The variable or variables listed above are not constant within `ID`.  Perhaps the values are in error. Type `reshape error` for a list of the problem observations.
>
> Either that, or the values vary because they should vary, in which case you must either add the variables to the list of `xij` variables to be reshaped, or drop them.

Why is my code wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Using the data as illustrated in the screenshot, the following works for me:

```
clear

input ID VisitNum str6 date Injury_1 Injury_2 Injury_3 gender
1 1 "12-Mar" 1 2  3 0
2 1 "2-Apr"  4 .  . 1
1 2 "23-Jun" 1 2  . 0
3 1 "1-Feb"  5 6  . 1
1 3 "30-Aug" 8 9 10 0
end

reshape wide date Injury_1 Injury_2 Injury_3, i(ID) j(VisitNum)

order ID gender
list, abbreviate(15)

     +----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
     | ID   gender    date1   Injury_11   Injury_21   Injury_31    date2   Injury_12   Injury_22   Injury_32    date3   Injury_13   Injury_23   Injury_33 |
     |----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  1. |  1        0   12-Mar           1           2           3   23-Jun           1           2           .   30-Aug           8           9          10 |
  2. |  2        1    2-Apr           4           .           .                    .           .           .                    .           .           . |
  3. |  3        1    1-Feb           5           6           .                    .           .           .                    .           .           . |
     +----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The command provided is *not* valid Stata syntax.